# nginx not forcing http to https

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a website groupsitedev.com . it does not forces website to httpd always. i have following setup done, but still it loads some of the links from http.
Here is configuration:

```
 server {
        listen *:80 default_server;
        if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use only return 301 as well, without if, here is screenshot of error i get

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqqdbmwl4vf43qp/error.JPG?dl=0

But still it does not forces all links to move to https.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use [if](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in Nginx block configuration.

The following config will redirect all requests to https

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: no success, i get this issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqqdbmwl4vf43qp/error.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Then you're probably doing something else wrong in your config. This configuration fragment is standard and works fine.

Comment: @FarhanThe configuration works http://prntscr.com/gbsbwb

The problem is that you request an HTTP resource from https url, and the browser blocks the [mix content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Comment: but my configuration is only this at port 80, nothing else. so why it stops to block mix-content? when i have forced it to stay on https?

Comment: @spilia, how can i force all resources of http to be loaded on https?

Comment: @Farhan the block comes from the browser, not from the webserver. If you check Nginx's access log you will see that you don't have access log for that Url.

Comment: It is not possible. You have to define the correct URL in your HTML / PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the links on your site code or configuration.

The site configuration might have a setting for base URL, you need to make sure you have `https` in it.

It there is not such a setting, then you need to replace `http://path/to/some/pic.jpg` with `/path/to/some/pic.jpg`, and you will make browser request using the protocol which was used to request the page itself.

Or if the resource comes from a different domain, then you can replace it with `//example.com/path/to/some/pic.jpg`.